# Bootstrap 3, Adding button to list-group misaligns everything else vertically

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to achieve a simple thing:
I'm taking the basic example of a `list-group` with badges from de Bootstrap 3 Components documentation [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group-badges).
The problem is that I need a button in the beginning of the line, but that is making the main text vertically misaligned and the `pull-right` text aligned at the top.

Please check [this bootply](http://www.bootply.com/129047).

Thanks.

Comment: Try specifying a `line-height: 3` to both spans. But is invalid to have a button inside an anchor.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code like this:

*See updated bootply:* http://www.bootply.com/129053

**HTML**

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <span class="badge">67512</span>
    <button>w</button>
    <a href="#" class="margin-sm">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <span class="badge">67512</span>
    <button>w</button>
    <a href="#" class="margin-sm">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit
    </a>

  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.margin-sm,.list-group-item .badge {
    margin: 4px;
}
```

I don't know if that's your desired effect....

Comment: I've updated it with more examples and with my desired effect included: http://www.bootply.com/129053
The thing is, if I need a larger button in there, I must re-calculate the margin of the pull-right span. :(

Comment: So, yes it can be hacked, but shouldn't bootstrap do it automatically without creating custom css, since they say in the documentation that nearly any html can be added inside of a `list-group-item`?